# custom pager/ formfilter/ buildquery doesn't process filter data into query

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, pager

I have an action requiring to use a formfilter, pager and a specific table method:

```
$this->filterForm = new OrganisationFormFilter();
$this->filterForm->setTableMethod('retrieveMemberOrganisations');
$this->filterForm->bind($searchParams);
$v = $this->filterForm->getValues();
$q = $this->filterForm->buildQuery($v);

$this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Organisation', 50);
$this->pager->setQuery($q->orderBy(implode(' ',$this->getSort())));
$this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page',1));
$this->pager->init();

public function retrieveMemberOrganisations(Doctrine_Query $q){

    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();
    $q->
    select("$rootAlias.*")->
    addSelect('m.id, sc.id, cat.id, cat.number_key')->
    innerJoin ("$rootAlias.CurrentMember c")->
    innerJoin ("$rootAlias.Membership m")->
    innerJoin ('m.LatestMembership lm')->
    innerJoin ('m.MembershipSubcategory sc')->
    innerJoin ('sc.MembershipCategory cat');

    return $q;

}
```

Problem is that the filter settings are not processed at all. I have checked that values in $v are set, but they don't seem to be reflected in $q. Also when I stop with a debugger on entry to retrieveMemberOrganisations, $q doesnt contrain the filter settings either. Is this the right order of code that I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually using the formFilter to do something like that. Instead of using

```
$q = $this->filterForm->buildQuery($v);
```

use

```
$q = $this->filterForm->getQuery();
```

I'm not using the **setTableMethod** method, but think that should work.